# Swift wait if required for asynchronous result

Tags: swift, async-await, semaphore

I am learning how to use completion handlers and dispatch. There is a function with two optional parameters (`groupName` and `groupId`). If `groupName` is given, `groupId` must be retrieved using this name.

This is what i have tried to wait if required for the method to complete before proceeding however the semaphore just waits indefinitely.

```
func getTaskId(uid: String, groupName: String?, groupId: String?, taskName: String, handler: @escaping (Array<String>?, Error?) -> Void) {
    var id: String? // this is groupId not task id *
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
    if let groupName = groupName {
        getGroupId(uid: uid, groupName: groupName) {(groupId, groupIdErr) in
            if let err = groupIdErr {
                handler(nil, err)
                return
            } else {
                id = groupId!
                semaphore.signal()
            }
        }
    } else if let unwrappedId = groupId {
        id = unwrappedId
        semaphore.signal()
    } else {
        let err = xErrors.getTaskIdErr(message: "Failed to get group id")
        handler(nil, err)
        return
    }
    semaphore.wait()
    guard let finalId = id else {return} // groupId will be used now
    // use groupId to continue and get taskId...
}
```

What is the correct way to do something like this? Waiting for the result of another method but only `if` required to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to force an asynchronous task to become synchronous. Don't do that.

Reduce the function to retrieve only the id.

```
func getTaskId(uid: String, groupName: String?, groupId: String?, completion: @escaping (Result<String,Error>) -> Void) {
    if let groupName = groupName {
        getGroupId(uid: uid, groupName: groupName) { groupId, groupIdErr in
            if let err = groupIdErr {
                completion(.failure(err))
            } else {
                completion(.success(groupId))
            }
        }
    } else if let unwrappedId = groupId {
        completion(.success(unwrappedId))
    } else {
       let err = xErrors.getTaskIdErr(message: "Failed to get group id")
       completion(.failure(err))
    }
}
```

Call it and in the completion handler process the id

```
getTaskId(uid: "1", groupName: "foo", groupId: nil) { result in 
   switch result {
   case .success(let groupId): 
      // do something with groupId...

   case .failure(let error): print(error)
   }

}
```

---

Another approch is to declare a function

```
func doSomething(with groupId : String) {}
```

And change `getTaskId` to

```
func getTaskId(uid: String, groupName: String, completion: @escaping (Result<String,Error>) -> Void) {
    getGroupId(uid: uid, groupName: groupName) { groupId, groupIdErr in
        if let err = groupIdErr {
            completion(.failure(err))
        } else {
            completion(.success(groupId))
        }
    }
}
```

And use it

```
if let groupName = groupName {
     getTaskId(uid: "1", groupName: groupName) { result in 
       switch result {
       case .success(let groupId): 
          doSomething(with : groupId)

       case .failure(let error): print(error)
       }
} else if groupId = groupId {
    doSomething(with : groupId)
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. i think i have the same comment as the above answer. this looks like it will return the `groupId` from the `getTaskId` function. Whereas I want to get `groupId` using `getGroupId` if not given to then use later to find `taskId` which is not shown. I don't want to return `groupId` from `getTaskId`... (Also, thanks for teaching me how to use `Result`, was trying to learn today that helped!)

Comment: My code is similar to yours. If `groupName` is given it gets the groupId asynchronously and returns it. If groupId is given it returns that immediately. Another way is to create a function `doSomethingWithGroupId` and call it directly if the groupId is available otherwise call it after retrieving it from the group name.

Comment: thanks i will follow the code you posted to refactor mine to get it working (i edited to add the rest of the code in my method).

Comment: Refactored my code and works great! Very helpful answer for many reasons.  Thank you

Comment: You may also look into promises later on. Read about "Callback Hell". Here are two articles [Avoiding Callback Hell in Swift](https://swiftrocks.com/avoiding-callback-hell-in-swift.html) and [Managing async code in Swift](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/managing-async-code-in-swift-d7be44cae89f). I recommend using [PromiseKit](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit). @andy

Comment: @user10447655 thank you for the information! I'll look into those